# Hall-Effect Current Sensor Output Voltage Difference (26.4 mV/A)

Tags: sensor, adc, hall-effect

I am using a hall effect current sensor. Its part number is ACS781LLRTR-050B-T from Allegro MicroSystems. In my circuit, I'm reading its output voltage to calculate current with MCU.

With no load, I read output voltage of current sensor as 2215 mV and use this value as zero current value. When the load is connected, it draws 2.3 A which means the output voltage of the current sensor must be 2286 mV, because the sensitivity of the sensor is 26.4 mV/A. However, in the MCU the voltage read is 2331 mV, which is higher than the expected 2286 mV.

What is the problem? What might be the solution?

[Hall effect sensor datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS781-Datsaheet.ashx)

[image: schematic of the related part of the circuit]

Comment: Are you measuring an AC current? How do you know your current is 2.3 amps?

Comment: No we are measuring DC current. We measured current with external multimeter when load is connected.

Comment: Be precise about this - what is the load and what is the supply that feeds the load.

Comment: Supply is 12.4 V DC power supply,  load is custom 5.3 ohm.

Comment: How DC stable is the 12.4 volt supply - what ripple voltages are present?

Comment: There is no ripple voltage. Is there a calibration method for this sensor which can be done with MCU? Problem is not in supply or load. Noise is very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem. After trials with different loads (1A, 2A, 3A  and so on), we realised that current sensor sensitivity is 36mV/A. We think that it might be because of the op-amp gains after the current sensor.
Thank you all for your efforts.